# center custom list bullet vertically

Tags: html, css

I replaced the default list bullets with a custom unicode.

```css
.listItem {
  list-style: none;
}

.listItem:before {
  content: '\25A0';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="listItem">
    <a>
       A Link
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My question is how can I center this custom bullet? I tried `vertical-align:middle` but this didn't help.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Center this list item in the center of the page? Vertically or horizontally. A screenshot with the desired result would help alot.

Comment: I updated my post I hope this makes it clear

Comment: it already looks that that to me

Comment: No, sorry, they are not centered vertically

Comment: There's no elegant solution to this, it's either `display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-?px)` or `position: relative; bottom: ?px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using character the only idea I came into is to position char using `position: relative`.

However, most probably the better approach is to use `display: block` for `:before`, which I showed in snippet 2.

#### Snippet 1

```css
.listItem {
  list-style: none;
}

.listItem:before {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
  content: '\25A0';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="listItem">
    <a>
       A Link
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Snippet 2

This approach is based on `:before` element which we give dimensions, so it's more predictable how it'll be displayed. `padding` for `listItem` creates distance between text and `:before` element. Precise values can be adjusted.

```css
.listItem {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 12px;
}

.listItem:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="listItem">
    <a>
       A Link
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

SVG answer:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"><circle style="fill:#A7A7A7;" cx="10" cy="10" r="5"/></svg>')
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-position-y: center
    padding-left: 2rem
}
```

Comment: I've spent **hours** trying to make this work - you really saved me here, thanks!!